# Backward compatibility :: iOS sdks 8.3 as base sdks and 7.1 simulators

Tags: ios, xcode6, ios7.1, ios8.3, xcode6.3.1

I have developed an iOS app with iOS sdks 8.3 and 8.3 simulator. it works fine.

I tested the same app with iOS sdks 8.3 as base sdks and 7.1 simulators.

My doubts.

1. is it enough for sdks 7 and 7 simulators combinations?
2. do I need to download iOS 7 sdks?
3. I don't have developer account yet so I can not download it. is there any way I can get it if it is required?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the simulators is not enough, try and get your hands on some iOS device, even a friends, just to see that it works. From experience, Ive had apps perform differently on simulator vs iPhone. Apps can perform differently on different devices also, like the iPhone 4 vs iPhone 6. But if you are really stuck, try your best to get your hands on any of the devices (iPhone4 upwards), otherwise you are taking a risk. It also takes around 8 days to get your app reviewed, and you need a developer account to submit to the store.